# Custom error message for gatling assertions

Tags: java, scala, junit, performance-testing, gatling

How to add a custom error message for gatling assertions

Current Behavior:-

> details("My Scenario").requestsPerSec.between(20, 25)

The above code allows validating the requests per second but unable to pass a custom message when assertion fails . (Like the assertions in Junit libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible as of current version (3.6.1). Contributions welcome.